# Ligatures in (Graphite) TrueType fonts

Tags: fonts, luatex, context, fontspec, context-mkiv

When using ConTeXt MkIV (i.e. with the LuaTeX engine), I’ve noticed that ligatures don’t work properly for some TrueType fonts, even though they do work in LuaLaTeX or even LibreOffice.  As far as I can tell, the common link is Graphite, but that might be a red herring.

As an example, I’ll compare `Charis SIL` (TrueType/Graphite), `DejaVu Serif` (plain? TrueType), and `Linux Libertine O` (OpenType).

### ConTeXt:

```
\usetypescript[charissil]
\usetypescript[dejavu]
\usetypescript[libertine]

\starttext

\title{\CONTEXT\ MkIV}
\tfd

\setupbodyfont[charissil]
Charis SIL: Difficult

\setupbodyfont[dejavu]
DejaVu Serif: Difficult

\setupbodyfont[libertine]
Linux Libertine O: Difficult

\stoptext
```

### LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\section*{Lua\LaTeX}
\Huge

\fontspec{Charis SIL}
Charis SIL: Difficult

\fontspec{DejaVu Serif}
DejaVu Serif: Difficult

\fontspec{Linux Libertine O}
Linux Libertine O: Difficult

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image]

As can be seen, `Charis SIL` lacks the proper `ffi` ligature in the ConTeXt output.

So, how can I use `Charis SIL` properly in ConTeXt?  I’ve tried a few ligature options to `\definefontfeature`, as listed in the ConTeXt manual, but these make no difference and seem to OpenType-only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Charis SIL enables the `ffi` ligature for latin scripts. Either activate this feature locally

```
\setupbodyfont[charissil]
{\feature[+][latn]Charis SIL: Difficult}
```

or globally

```
\definefontfeature [default] [default] [script=latn]
```

Comment: @Marko: Thanks, that works!  Unless someone has a reason why I shouldn’t add that feature to my default environment template (I only write English documents), I’ll flag that as the accepted answer.